# Why my swipeleft or swiperight doesn't work with hammerjs?

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I am using Hammerjs and I just implemented this, but for some weird reason doesn't work. While if I use the dragleft or dragright, it does work but in a weird way where instead of going to the next one, goes to the 2nd image.

Here is the code

```
            //Hammer(sliderH).on('swiperight',function () {       
        $('.slide-horizontal').hammer().on('swiperight', function() {
            $('.slide-horizontal > div').animate({
                'left': '+=' + sliderWidth
            }, 600);
        });        
        //Hammer(sliderH).on('swipeleft', function () {
        $('.slide-horizontal').hammer().on('swipeleft', function() {
            $('.slide-horizontal > div').animate({
                'left': '-=' + sliderWidth
            }, 600);    
        });
```

Here I have an example of what I am trying to do.
http://labs.lesevades.com/recipe-book/